# How to keep DB in sync when using microservices architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices

Im about to learn how microservices architecture work. So far i unserstood that each microservice need its own database, which make sense.

So lets say we have a customer microservice which is responsible for creating a customer and returning a list of customers. The service will ofcource have it own customer DB.

Lets say we have very high load on this ervice, so we chooce to scale out 20x.

Så we have 20 microservices and each have its own DB, and all the services is behind a load balancer.

Now a client wants to create a customer, load balancer sends client request to service 9/20, and the customer is created.

On the next request the same client wants to be sure that customer is created and want to view the list of the customers, on the request LB sends him to service 11/20.

Now how do i make sure that service 9/20 synced the newly created customer to the db of service 11/20?

In MSSQL there are functionality to keep DB in sync by before alowing the initial commit, to save the data in all the other databases first, but this approach will give problems in the long run, because the more services there are the longer time it will take to make a commit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> each microservice need its own database

A separate DB per microservice is not a prerequisite (nor a requirement, really).

You can have as many microservices as you want working on top of the same database, but use different schemas for example.

The bounded context of a microservice should be the boundary.

> Lets say we have very high load on this service, so we choose to scale out 20x.

Scaling to (X) instances of the same microservice does not mean necessarily having a separate database per each instance of that same service.

Most databases are designed with concurrent connections, users, transactions in mind. a single database instance (with some optimistic concurrency) can handle hundreds (if not thousands) of concurrent connections gracefully.

If you explicitly chose to have a separate DB per instance of the same service, then you will have to sync those databases up. and, most likely, data consistency will suffer for it.

Here are some suggestions:

- use a single database per microservice (not per instance) no matter how many instances are using it. And only consider a DB per instance when you're sure a single DB cannot handle the load.
- Use a shared cache layer on top of the DB (maybe redis cache)
- Use a database cluster to deal with high load/availability of databases.

Comment: A separate DB per microservices is desired sometimess, for instance, a microservices needs to serve full-text search in that case NoSQL would be a better approach. In this case, how do you think we handle data consistency?

Comment: A separate DB per microservice is actually **the** number one prerequisite. Otherwise you build a Distributed Monolith. It can be ok to have a physical db with boundaries, but that usuall ends up in a monolith aswell. https://youtu.be/oHQH4zuR58I?t=518

Answer (score 21):

While using the same database for multiple services may be possible, it should be avoided as it'll create a higher coupling between services than is desirable. E.g. a database downtime will affect all services with sharing but only a single one if each service has their own one.

To avoid a "distributed monolith" of services that do synchronous calls to each other (e.g. using REST), you could work with a streaming based approach. Each service would publish a change event whenever its data changes, and other services can subscribe to these streams. So they can react to data changes relevant to them, e.g. by storing a local version of the data (in a representation suited to their needs, e.g. just columns they are interested int) in their own database. That way they can provide their functionality, also if other services aren't available for some time. Naturally, such architecture employs semantics of eventual consistency, but usually that's inevitable in distributed systems anyways.

One way to set up such data streams is change data capture CDC, which will trail the databases log files (e.g. the binlog in MySQL) and publish corresponding events for each INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. One open source CDC tool is [Debezium](http://debezium.io/) which comes with connectors for MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB as well as (work-in-progress as of now) Oracle and SQL Server. It can be used with Apache Kafka as the streaming backbone or as library within your Java applications, allowing you to stream data changes into other streaming layers such as Pulsar or Kinesis with just a bit of code. One nice advantage of using persistent topics for the change events, e.g. with Kafka, is that new services can come up and re-read the entire change stream (depending on the topic's retention policy) or just get the current state of each record to do an initial seed of their local database.

(Disclaimer: I'm the lead of Debezium)

Comment: Using a single backing database for multiple instances of the same service doesn't need to be avoided.  Yes, the single failure point needs to be considered, but pooling the database is a simple and effective option to resolve that issue.  And it's a much simpler solution than Kafka event streams and working to keep multiple datastore in sync.

Comment: I was referring to different services, not multiple instances of one and the same service.

Comment: Even different services using the same database don't create coupling if you are careful to keep each services' data "private".  That it, each service should keep its own data in its own table(s) or even schema.  Likewise, no service should query another service's data directly from the database-- if a service needs access to another service's data, it should call the service's public interface instead of accessing its neighbor's private data.

Comment: Sure, when having to share a database, that's the way to go. Doesn't mean there's no coupling, though: the services share the same database technology and version, downtime of the DB impacts all of them, they're competing on CPU resources, etc.

Comment: @drhender what if a service needs a **NoSQL** instead of **RDBMS**? And even if we have private data using our own table or schema, but the other team who is responsible for **microservice B** needs to **add column** to the table which is owned by **another team**? In short, how would you avoid using Kafka in those cases?

Comment: @Gunnar, sure there is a loose coupling of sorts be using the same db and version, but that isn't a entirely a bad thing.  Do you really want to run a system where your services each deploy their own DB, with their own version requirements?  That makes for a really messy system.  And again, address database issues where they belong-- in the data layer without pushing those concerns to every service.  Running on K8s, there's no need for DB downtime and elasticity (auto-scaling) will handle CPU resource contention.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar, I didn't say a service couldn't require a different technology, such as a NoSQL database or that Kafka was bad.  Those are both fine technologies that fill a need.  If you need them, add them to your stack and use them.  But using a database per service instance and a message bus to keep them in sync is unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Going to multiple databases only changes one problem of software architecture for one of distributed coordination, the latter which, imho, is a much more difficult problem.

People suggest using event systems, which means each single service now has to have its own little solution for distributed coordination of data, ACID goes out the window. Look at the database landscape and you'll see that this is not a easy, or completely solved issue. And then go to distributed coordinated transactions...

There are many times were you would prefer downtime to having N databases in completely unknown inconsistent states. Also the perception of up time is misleading, yes your services are up but if they have inconsistent views of the same data or missing data (missed events) are they really functioning? or will they produce inconsistent and errored results?

Either you have two services that completely does not rely on having the same data, or you need a shared consistent data layer. But copying between N dbs using event systems and hoping for the best, well, your choice.

The question of distribution, persistence, consistency and availability should be treated at the storage layer, and not adhoc by each service in the application layer. It takes care and specialized dedicated knowledge of many minds to make such a system and even then there are flavors and trade offs (CAP theorem).

Lastly: Most people look to microservices to be able to develop and evolve their applications quicker than via monoliths. Dealing with distributed coordination and consistency of storage in each microservice will do the contrary.

Comment: Absolutely agree!  Using a single (pooled) database to resolve the issue of a single point of failure is far simpler than introducing multiple datastore that have to be kept in sync with an event bus.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved using the CQRS design pattern, which is separation of creation and viewing of entity by following asynchronous paradigm.

While creation, we push the entity persistence to Kafka/RabbitMQ and push that to database asynchronously. Materialised views can be created on the DB which makes the retrieval faster.